# What is the difference between NHibernate and Hibernate?

Tags: java, .net, hibernate, orm, nhibernate

Last month I started a new job at new company . This company use Nhibernate for .Net solutions . But I have not experienced that before. I have two year experience in Entityframework . As I googled I can not find difference between Nhibernate and Hibernate . I assume that , Nhibernate is Hibernate for .Net solutions . Is it true ? Can you say what is the difference from Hibarnate ?

Thanks ,

Comment: Given the difference in technologies there for sure are some differences in how they work. However, conceptually and on a high level I'd expect them to be very similar (I don't really know NHibernate but from what I've read it looks like this).

Answer (score 7):

Entity Framework (EF), NHibernate and Hibernate are full Object Relational Mappers (ORM).

EF and NHibernate are for .NET/C#. Hibernate is for Java.

Initially, Hibernate was developed and was in use for Java. Then after, it was ported to NHibernate for .NET/C#. Both are two different projects; developed and maintained separately.

Both NHibernate and Hibernate were structurally similar in beginning. I am not sure if that is the case now. But, many times, if I find solution for Hibernate on net, mostly the same (or similar) works for NHibernate as well. I never used Hibernate, so I cannot say about there similarity for sure; but as per my observation, they are near to same.

Comment: Thanks for answer , that is all I want to ask  , helpful for me .